# How to rewrite Objective C to RubyMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rubymotion

I am trying to reset the `UIPickerView` on button click. After searching StackOverflow I found:

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

I rewrote it in Ruby like this:

```
  def reset_picker
    @picker.reloadAllComponents
    @picker.selectRow( 0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
  end
```

The above only resets the first component; how do I reset all three components? I know it has something to do the inComponent: `0` in the `reset_picker` method.

Below are the `UIPickerView` method calls:

```
  def numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView)
    component_options.count
  end

  def pickerView(pickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent: component)
    component_options[component].count
  end

  def pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
    component_options[component][row]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - The `inComponent: 0` relates to the index of the component.

With that in mind, to reset all three components you just need to:

```
def reset_picker
    @picker.reloadAllComponents
    @picker.selectRow( 0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    @picker.selectRow( 0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    @picker.selectRow( 0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)
end
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Minor thing, but you shouldn't need the initial call to `reloadAllComponents`, I just kept it to fit with your code.

Comment: You're right, it works fine without the `reloadAllComponents`. Could I put this in a block with `self.numberOfComponentsInPickerView.times do |x|`?